# How can I programmatically copy ActiveModel validators from one model to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm writing a library that will require programmatically copying validations from one model to another, but I'm stumped on how to pull this off.

I have a model that is an `ActiveModel::Model` with some validation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

And another model that I'd like to have the same validations:

```
class UserForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

Now I'd like to give `UserForm` the same validations as `User`, and without modifying `User`. Copying the validators over doesn't work, because `ActiveModel::Validations` hooks into callbacks during the validation check:

```
UserForm._validators = User._validators
UserForm.new.valid?
# => true             # We wanted to see `false` here, but no validations
                      # are actually running because the :validate callback
                      # is empty.
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an easy way that I can see to programmatically give one model another's validation callbacks and still have it work. I think my best bet is if I can ask Rails to regenerate the validation callbacks based on the validators that are present at a given moment in time.

Is that possible? If not, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Checking into the code of `activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb` reveals how this can be achieved:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb, line 60
def validates_presence_of(*attr_names)
  validates_with PresenceValidator, _merge_attributes(attr_names)
end
```

So I guess I would try to hook into `validates_with` with an alias_method

`alias_method :orig_validates_with :validates_with`

Now you have a chance to get ahold of the values passed, so you can store them somewhere and retrieve them when you need to recreate the validation on `UserForm`

```
alias_method :orig_validates_with, :validates_with
def validates_with(*args)
  # save the stuff you need, so you can recreate this method call on UserForm
  orig_validates_with(*args)
end
```

Then you should be able to just call `UserForm.validates_with(*saved_attrs)`. Sorry this is not something you can just copy/paste, but this should get you started. HTH

Comment: If it's done this way, then the downstream model (`UserForm` in this case) has to do something different than every other `ActiveModel::Model` -- specifically its validation cannot occur with `valid?` but rather must happen with an aliased version of `validates_with`. That breaks the API contract. So I'm uncertain about this direction, but I appreciate the answer.

Comment: I think my proposed process only replaces *how* you setup your validations, it should still be possible to use valid? to validate the instances